# Pandas product dtype

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a pandas data frame with two columns of booleans.  I want to take the product along the columns, so :

```
df.product(axis=1)
```

This returns the product, but the data type is always int64.  Looking at the pandas source, it looks like `_make_stat_function` (which is what product appears to be calling) can take a `dtype` kwarg.

1. Is this the case?
2. What is required to make this work?  I have tried specifying dtype as a string, python type, and numpy data type.  All no joy.

### Links

Pandas docos: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html

Source:

product is dispatched from here:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5062

to here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5246

Comment: What dtype does it return?

Comment: always returns int64

Comment: Does your distribution actually have this `_validate_kwargs` function?  It may be too new.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/3d2f11594ab546874aad07ccf08b4193ad4a12db

This `_validate_kwargs` function is new, very new (8 days).  It is in the main repository, but it probably isn't in anyone's distribution.

> BUG: Prevent abuse of kwargs in stat functions
>   Addresses issue #12301 by filtering `kwargs` argument in stat
>   functions to prevent the passage of clearly invalid arguments while at
>   the same time maintaining compatibility with analogous `numpy`
>   functions.

So it's been added to keep people from using obviously bogus, non-numpy like `kwargs`.  But I don't see why they couldn't have just used:

```
_validate_kwargs(name, kwargs)
```

to block all `kwargs`, since they aren't being used in this function (or any other in `generic.py`).

================================

The `_make_stat_function` that you link has a:

```
_validate_kwargs(name, kwargs, 'out', 'dtype')
```

statement.  But I don't see any further use of `kwargs` in the returned function.  I'm not familiar with `pandas` code, but it looks like that `validate` call is somehow testing the `prod` function for these `kwargs`.

My slightly older `pandas` version does not have this `validate` statement.  It accepts a `dtype` argument, but does nothing with it.  It also accepts a `test` kwarg argument, with the same non-effect.

I'd suggest digging through the `pandas` issues and pull requests to find out when and why this `validate` call was added.  It doesn't look like it is doing anything significant in this case.

---

`_validate_kwargs` is in the same `generic.py` file.  All it is doing here is checking that `kwargs` does not contain anything but 'out' and `dtype`.  'name' is just used in the error message.  So with this test `product` will raise an error if you give it other `kwargs`, but be ok if you give it `dtype` or `out`.  But that doesn't guarantee that it uses them.

Comment: this was added to have numpy compat for args which we ignore (out) while not actually having them in the signature ; the validation is added to provide a nice error message if a kw arg is invalid (eg df.product(axi=1) should raise

Answer (score -1):

As for your specific problem, taking the product of booleans converted to `int`s is the same as checking if all the booleans are `True`.

Simply do: `df.all(axis=1)`

On the more specific case of product, the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html) does not include any dtype manipulation.

However, if you absolutely care for dtype conservation you can do the following (provided your data is well defined, which is floats / ints, etc.), which converts the resulting dtype from product to your initial dtype.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1, 0.2, 0.6], 'b': [2, 3, 4]})
>>> df.dtypes
a    float64
b      int64
dtype: object
>>> prod = df.product()
>>> prod
a     0.012
b    24.000
dtype: float64

>>> prod.astype(df.dtypes)
a    0.012
b       24
dtype: object
```

Comment: While this works for this specific use case, the larger question still remains.  Can df.product accept a dtype kwarg?

Comment: This is making an astype call though.  The documentation suggest that df.product can take a kwarg that is dtype=some_dtype.  Can it?

Comment: Please indicate why this is so important to make the operation in one call rather than two? Where did you read that there was a dtype kwargs? I just see a kwargs with no documentation associated, which seems to tell us that there is nothing important regarding the kwargs, it's just the way pandas is made. I also tried the usual aliases for dtype (astype, astypes, dtype, dtypes) used in pandas, with no success.

Comment: (1) curiosity if this is a bug, (2) clarity in the call, (3) potential to avoid a copy without having to include astype(copy=False).  Also, assuming that **kwargs is unimportant because it is not auto-documented is naive.  It is simply indicative that kwargs is potentially being passed through to another function, where those kwargs could be important.